# IF ELSE statement in java delete sql joption message

Tags: java, oracle, swing, if-statement, joptionpane

i tried to create a if statement but don't work, if found isbn book in jtable, show message "book" delete" else "book" don't found. it's possible?

```
 private void elimina_libroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      
   Connection conn = Connessione.ConnecrDb();
   Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet emps = null;       
      boolean found = false;
    try{          
      if(emps.next()) 
      found= true;
        String sql= "DELETE FROM progetto.libro WHERE isbn =?";  
        pst=(OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);            
        pst.setString (1, txt_isbn.getText());          
        pst.execute();               

    if (!found)
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LIBRO ELIMINATO"); 
   else{    
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "BOOK NOT FOUND","ERRORE",jOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE); 

    }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
     {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
                }
```

but don't work, can you help me? thanks

i change code with this

```
Connection conn = Connessione.ConnecrDb();
   Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet emps = null;

    try{

        String sql= "DELETE FROM progetto.libro WHERE isbn =?"; 

        pst=(OraclePreparedStatement) (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);            
          pst.setString (1, txt_isbn.getText());          
        int deleted = pst.executeUpdate();               

if (deleted == 0) {

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LIBRO ELIMINATO");
         Update_table(); 


          }else
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LIBRO NON TROVATO");  

    }

    catch (Exception e)
     {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

    }
```

but if i insert a incorrect isbn the message is: "book delete", if i insert a correct isbn the message is "book not found" and if i insert again correct isbn the message is "book delete" and the book delete from databae.

Comment: This code would throw NullPointerException here - `if(emps.next())`. Is that the actual code you are running?

Comment: what do you mean by not work? where you create instance of `emps` it is null when you are calling next method on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    pst=(PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);            
    pst.setString (1, txt_isbn.getText());          
    int deleted = pst.executeUpdate();               

    if (deleted == 0) {
    ...
```

> int executeUpdate() throws SQLException
>
> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which
>   must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
>   such as a DDL statement.
>
> Returns:
>       either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Comment: I tried with your solution but work strange. I update my first post. thanks a lot.

Comment: pst.executeUpdate() will return a number of rows deleted.

if (deleted == 0) -> nothing was deleted. so: LIBRO NON TROVATO
if (deleted > 0) -> book(s) deleted, so: LIBRO ELIMINATO

Comment: @Joeblade ahh right!!! Now I understand it. In fact, fixing the code (inverting) and now works perfectly. thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `deleted` was interpreted wrong. Also for every prepareStatement better close it, as you are contacting the SQL driver.

No need to import Oracle classes; JDBC allows being vendor independant.

Best practice is using try-with-resources which automatically closes the pst.

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM progetto.libro WHERE isbn = ?"; 
try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    pst.setString (1, txt_isbn.getText());          
    int deletionsCount = pst.executeUpdate();               
    if (deletionsCount > 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LIBRO ELIMINATO");
        Update_table(); 
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LIBRO NON TROVATO");  
    }
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```